# FBConnect in iphone 4.0 version is displayed as in browser

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I developed an App with FBConnect using new Facebook SDK.
It worked fine in 3.0 devices/simulators.  But as the code is executed in 4.0, the fbconnect page is displayed as in browser i.e showing addressbar at the top, some controls in the bottom..  what the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the method

```
- (void)authorizeWithFBAppAuth:(BOOL)tryFBAppAuth
                    safariAuth:(BOOL)trySafariAuth
```

and pass both parameters as NO